# Windows Hosting Suggestions

Tags: hosting

I've been developing a Silverlight-c# client-server game that has now gotten to the point that it should be hosted for a small amount of people can test it out.  The problem is that I've never looked at windows hosting before an am thus a total noob.  I'm looking for a place that allows me to run a c# command line program (the game server), and allows me to open non-standard ports for communication.  Since this is only for testing, I'm going for min specs etc.

Comment: While I'm unsure where this question belongs, it doesn't pertain to software development so it probably doesn't belong here.

Comment: I removed the tags except for 'hosting'.  Perhaps that helps?

Comment: It is a stretch at best to see how this fits on a development forum.

Comment: asking about commercial hosting of software is not outside the purview of StackOverflow. This question is not off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want raw hosting as you described, Amazon cloud, as Paul said, is probably your best bet. *However*... given that you are doing a C#/Silverlight application, I would suggest that you highly consider [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) for your hosting, as it scales rather nicely and the [free trial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) is a great way to test.

You will likely have to refactor aspects of your server to do this. *But* you would have had to do that anyway, since hosting of servers in a console is an unstable choice -- at a minimum you would have wanted to use a Windows Service for your game server if only for the auto-start option.

Comment: Currently I use a MySQL database with the C# (Weird combination I guess?)  Is Azure def the better option then?

Comment: @will well.... it sounds like you've already got more work done in a different direction than I would have thought given your chosen framework. It may be more work for you to run with Azure than with Amazon. You get a lot of administrative benefits with Azure, but you have to jump through a couple programmatic hoops to get them. I obviously don't know your codebase, but from what you've dropped, it may be more work than it's worth for Azure. The work might pay off in the long run... but you're the only one who can make that assessment.

Answer (score 2):

Just spin up an Amazon EC2 or Rackspace Cloud instance, easiest way by-far to do this.